# How to put a bootloader on a CD

Tags: nasm, bootloader, bios

I have written a simple bootloader in nasm. It will only write Hello world on the screen. But I doesn't know how to put it on a CD/DVD. I have a .bin file.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an iso and store your floppy image as the bootloader for the iso filesystem. This is fairly simple with mkisofs. If you have a folder called cdcontents containing your your .img file (boot.img), you can do this:

```
mkisofs -R -b boot.img -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -o bootable.iso cdcontents
```

Then you could probably use most cd burning programs with your .iso file to burn it to a disc. The programs you tried probably aren't made to convert a bootable floppy to a bootable iso and were most likely trying to transfer nonexistent files from the floppy. For more information look on http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootable_CD.

Comment: So VirtualBox can't open these .iso files (I want to test it before I try on a real computer). Is that right?

Comment: It should be able to. Try it.

Comment: A floppy disc's bootloader is the first 512 bytes. But booting from a cd is different. What you want to do is make your cd, when booted, use your floppy image as the bootloader.

Comment: The El-Torito standard describes how it is possible to boot from cds.

Comment: `mkisofs` implements this standard.

Comment: I have tried it in VirtualBox, but it doesn't work well. When I start the test it happends nothing. It doesn't say that there is no bootable media, that's not the problem. When it starts there only is an _ on the screen. And now I'm going to say something I have said many times before: what's wrong?                             P.S. Sorry it took so long before I wrote anything here.

Comment: Yes I have tried it, and it worked. But that isn't what I want to. I wants to test the iso image before I tries to use it on a cd.

Comment: try it with qemu or bochs as well

Answer (score 1):

The 'El Torito' CD specs allow you to burn the floppy disk image on the CD.

See here for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_(CD-ROM_standard)

If you already can put your bootloader on a FAT-formatted floppy, there shouldn't be much trouble to burn this image to the CD using standart.

See this link http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/CD-Writing-HOWTO-4.html#ss4.11  for the way to create a descent .iso file.

The 'mkisofs' command with -b and -c options would make such an .iso from you floppy disk image.

Comment: I didn't understand how to use El Torito and I doesn't have linux. Can I do this on Windows 7?

Comment: Just use something like Nero Burning ROM and set the "Bootable CD" option.

Comment: Is there any free application that can burn a "Bootable CD"?

Comment: El Torito is the standard for making bootable floppys.